# Return total value from tableview cell[swift]

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to add up all the total price at the right side of the tableview cell and display it at the bottom of the table view label, now the problem is, How do I compute the total of values from the tableview cell

[image: sum]

Comment: Create a right aligned label which sticks to the right side. Perform calculations(quantity*price) and show the value to that label.

Comment: @bobo , Do you need to get price value when row click?

Comment: @MohanSingh no, but i call the price value from core data

Answer (score 0):

You can use table view footer view to achieve your goal.

If you use storyboard, just drag and drop UIView with UILabel under custom cells, and make outlet to your view controller.

In place where you bind with data, make calculations and update outleted label.

Answer (score 0):

you have array of items with below attributes

- number of item
- price per item

calculate total by using loop to show total price.

and to show price of each cell item.

write do calculation in cellforrowatindexPath and show them for each row label assigned for total `price = total_items * price_per_item.`